# Jquery - getting the value of an id from a loop

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and trying to make code that gets the value of an id (if clicked) from a loop and append it to a new div. It's working. however, it only gets the first child value even if i clicked the other div.
Here is my Code:

```
<?php
  if($week < 10) {
   $week = '0'. $week;
  }
  for($day= 1; $day <= 7; $day++) {
    $d = strtotime($year ."W". $week . $day);
    $i = 0;
  ?>
  <div id="cal-btn" class="cal-btn">
    <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
      <?php echo date('l',$d ); ?>
       <br>
      <?php echo date('d M',$d);  ?>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="cal<?php echo $i; ?> " class="cal" value="<?php echo date('F d, Y',$d);  ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php
    $i++;
    }
    ?>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$(".cal-btn").click(function() {
        $(this).each(function() {
          var cal = $('#cal').val();
          $('.date-sc').append(cal);
        });
    });
```

Is there any way that i could get the value of an clicked div and append the value to a new div? Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an `id` must be unique.
The PHP loop you are using creates multiple times the same `id`.

Here is the markup produced by your code (with `$week = 40` and `$year = 2018`).
*(Use the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) to inspect your markup!)*

```
<div id="cal-btn" class="cal-btn">
  <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
    Monday<br>
    01 Oct
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="cal0 " class="cal" value="October 01, 2018">
</div>
<div id="cal-btn" class="cal-btn">
  <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
    Tuesday<br>
    02 Oct
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="cal0 " class="cal" value="October 02, 2018">
</div>
<div id="cal-btn" class="cal-btn">
  <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
    Wednesday<br>
    03 Oct
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="cal0 " class="cal" value="October 03, 2018">
</div>
<div id="cal-btn" class="cal-btn">
  <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
    Thursday<br>
    04 Oct
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="cal0 " class="cal" value="October 04, 2018">
</div>
<div id="cal-btn" class="cal-btn">
  <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
    Friday<br>
    05 Oct
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="cal0 " class="cal" value="October 05, 2018">
</div>
<div id="cal-btn" class="cal-btn">
  <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
    Saturday<br>
    06 Oct
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="cal0 " class="cal" value="October 06, 2018">
</div>
<div id="cal-btn" class="cal-btn">
  <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
    Sunday<br>
    07 Oct
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="cal0 " class="cal" value="October 07, 2018">
</div>
```

There is an attempt to use `$i` on the input's `id` to create unique ids... But since `$i` is setted to 0 at each loop iteration, it's a fail.

What you should do is to remove those ids:

```
<?php
// For this demo... I had to define those 2 variables.
$week = 40;
$year = 2018;

if($week < 10) {
    $week = '0'. $week;
}
for($day= 1; $day <= 7; $day++) {
    $d = strtotime($year ."W". $week . $day);
?>
<div class="cal-btn">
    <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
        <?php echo date('l',$d ); ?>
        <br>
        <?php echo date('d M',$d);  ?>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="cal" value="<?php echo date('F d, Y',$d);  ?>" />
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Which produces the HTML markup in this working snippet:

```js
$(".cal-btn").on("click",function(){
  var inputValue = $(this).find("input").val();
  alert(inputValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cal-btn">
    <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
        Monday<br>
        01 Oct
  </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="cal" value="October 01, 2018">
</div>
<div class="cal-btn">
    <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
        Tuesday<br>
        02 Oct
  </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="cal" value="October 02, 2018">
</div>
<div class="cal-btn">
    <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
        Wednesday<br>
        03 Oct
  </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="cal" value="October 03, 2018">
</div>
<div class="cal-btn">
    <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
        Thursday<br>
        04 Oct
  </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="cal" value="October 04, 2018">
</div>
<div class="cal-btn">
    <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
        Friday<br>
        05 Oct
  </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="cal" value="October 05, 2018">
</div>
<div class="cal-btn">
    <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
        Saturday<br>
        06 Oct
  </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="cal" value="October 06, 2018">
</div>
<div class="cal-btn">
    <div class="date d-flex justify-center-center">
        Sunday<br>
        07 Oct
  </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="cal" value="October 07, 2018">
</div>
```

About your click handler: the `.each()` loop is useless.
`$(this)` is the clicked element... And obviouly, there is only one!

But from `$(this)`, you can [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the hidden `input` and get the value.

I only alerted it here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. It's working great!

Comment: ;) I'm happy that you are.

Answer (score 0):

You were using `#cal` which will find an element with the id `cal`.  Try this:

```
$(".cal-btn").click(function(e) {
    var cal = $(e.target).find('.cal').val();
    $('.date-sc').append(cal);
});
```

`e.target` is the `div` that was clicked, and then by using `find('.cal')` it will search all children of that div that has the class `cal`, which is your hidden input that has the value you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's working :) appreciate your explanation